# Help me prove a modular congruence!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Show that $a^{42} \equiv 1 \pmod{1764}$ if $\gcd (a, 1764) = 1$. Use Euler's theorem.
>
> Hint: $1764 = 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 49$
>
> Hint: if t is a common multiple of $\phi(m)$ and $\phi(n)$, where the $\phi$ refers to Euler's totient function and $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, then $a^t \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Attempt:
I decomposed $1764$ into its prime factors, but I'm having trouble showing why it's true:
$a^{(42)(12)} \equiv 1 \pmod{1764}$

Comment: There is a typo between the problem statement $a^{42}\equiv 1 \pmod{1764}$ and your question $a^{(42)(12)}\equiv 1 \pmod{1764}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

$U(1764) \cong U(4) \times U(9) \times U(49) \cong C_2 \times C_6 \times C_{42}$.

Since $2$ and $6$ divide $42$, we have $g^{42}=1$ for all $g \in C_2 \times C_6 \times C_{42}$.

In terms of congruences and Euler's theorem, this reads:

$\quad a^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod 4$

$\quad a^{6} \equiv 1 \bmod 9$

$\quad a^{42} \equiv 1 \bmod 49$

and so

$\quad a^{42} \equiv 1 \bmod m$ for $m=4,9,49$.

By the Chinese remainder theorem, $a^{42} \equiv 1 \bmod 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 49$.

Comment: I tried another one: $a^{49} = a (mod 1547)$

Attempt: $1547 = 7*13*17$ 
$a^6 = 1 (mod 7*13)$
$a^6 = 1 (mod 91)$ 
$(a^{6})8 = 18 (mod 91)$

OTOH, $a^8 = 1 (mod 17)$

Because 17 and 91 are relatively prime, and 8 divides 48: $a^{48} = 1 (mod 91*17)$ = $a^{48} = 1 (mod 1547)$

Does this look right?

Comment: @D.Bergman, ask a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, not allowed to post yet!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use  [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html),

$\lambda(1764)=$lcm$(\lambda(7^2),\lambda(3^2),\lambda(2^2))=$lcm$(42,6,2)=42$